# How should I install cups-pdf from source?

Tags: software-installation

On Ubuntu 12.10, I want to install cups-pdf. Using `apt-get install cups-pdf` works okay, but I want to install it in code source.

This is what I've tried:

1. Download code from http://www.physik.uni-wuerzburg.de/~vrbehr/cups-pdf/src/
2. Build cups-pdf:

   ```
   gcc -o cups-pdf `cups-config --cflags` cups-pdf.c `cups-config --libs`
   ```
3. Run the following:

   ```
   cp cups-pdf /usr/lib/cups/backend/
   cp ../extra/cups-pdf.conf /etc/cups
   cp ../extra/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd  /usr/share/cups/model/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd 
   lpadmin -p PDFprinter -E -v cups-pdf:/ -P /usr/share/cups/model/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd 
   lpadmin -d PDFprinter
   ```
4. Try to print a file to PDF:

   ```
   lp Hello.c
   ```
5. **Nothing happened**

Comment: i fond answer [How_to_install_CUPS-PDF_OpenSolarisx86.pdf][1].

The pointer is :

    chmod 0700 /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf


  [1]: http://www.cups-pdf.de/contrib/How_to_install_CUPS-PDF_OpenSolarisx86.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you've found an answer that works, please write it up as an answer to your own question rather than as a comment. Also, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference rather than just pasting a URL.

Comment: sorry, i can't write it up as an answer to my question for my responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I presume there is a package ready for you that doesn't need to get build just running:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

The version of the package is 2.6.1. The same you are trying to build! If you still want to continue, lets check the instructions:

> Edit src/cups-pdf.h if you do not like /etc/cups as location for your
>      configuration files.

This probably is ok.

> To compile CUPS-PDF, invoke gcc in the src/ directory:
>
> `gcc -O9 -s -lcups -o cups-pdf cups-pdf.c`
>
> Note: you will have to have the deveopment package for CUPS installed
>            in order to build CUPS-PDF

You are not doing this correctly. You first need to install the CUPS development libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
```

Then compile it with the command above:

```
gcc -O9 -s -lcups -o cups-pdf cups-pdf.c
cups-pdf.c: In function ‘read_config_ppd’:
cups-pdf.c:289:3: warning: ‘ppdFirstOption’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/cups/ppd.h:431) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   option = ppdFirstOption(ppd_file);
   ^
cups-pdf.c:292:5: warning: ‘ppdNextOption’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/cups/ppd.h:433) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     option = ppdNextOption(ppd_file);
     ^
```

Those are build warnings, you can ignore them.

To install the binary, simply copy cups-pdf to the backend directory
   of CUPS (usually /usr/lib/cups/backend or /usr/lib64/...).

If you have a 64-bit system, the correct is /usr/lib64, if you have 32-bits the correct is /usr/lib.

> Now copy extra/cups-pdf.conf to /etc/cups (or whatever location you
>      selected in cups-pdf.h above). Here you can set all properties of
>      CUPS-PDF at runtime without the need for restarting any services.
>      (The defaults should work fine on most systems.)

This is OK.

> If you want to use the color PostScript driver that comes with
>      CUPS-PDF go to the extra/ subdirectory and copy CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd to
>      your CUPS model directory (usually /usr/share/cups/model [ /Generic ] ).
>      If you do not want to set any options via PPD (see section 3), use
>      CUPS-PDF_noopt.ppd instead.

Ok too. Now, I cheated and installed the package instead and it worked. If it's not working for you it must be due Ubuntu/Debian patchs. Apply those patches and try again.